# parsing this XML in C# for a SharePoint Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, xml, elements-xml

I have the below field xml which I get after calling a web service. I am getting the error

> Name cannot begin with the '=' character, hexadecimal value 0x3D. Line
>   1, position 2325.

```
<Field DisplayName='Maximum_x0020_characters_x0020_a' FillInChoice='TRUE' Format ='RadioButtons' Type ='Choice' StaticName ='Maximum_x0020_characters_x0020_a' Required='TRUE' Name='Maximum_x0020_characters_x0020_a'><Default></Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>True</CHOICE><CHOICE>False</CHOICE><CHOICE>True</CHOICE><CHOICE>False</CHOICE><CHOICE>>=255</CHOICE><CHOICE><=255</CHOICE><CHOICE>>=510</CHOICE><CHOICE><= 510</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>
```

Can anyone please suggest the correct way of replacing the special character. I tried replacing `&lt` and `&gt` for `>` and `<` but then I get another error.

Comment: may be this will help https://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/sharepoint-column-names-internal-name-mappings-for-non-alphabet/

Comment: Can you share the string or display name ? Where is "=" character in it.

Comment: u can see the xml which i have provided.. the Choice tag have >= as the value

Comment: also I tried doing this. but then I get error as Data at the root level is invalid.
 string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
                                                    if (FieldXml.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8))
                                                    {
                                                        FieldXml = FieldXml.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
                                                    }

Comment: I resolved it using <[[CDATA]]>. The XML format containg the special character was binded inside CDATA. IT worked!!!

Comment: Great ! Can you put it as answer. So that it will be helpful for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the special character part in CDATA tag and it worked. For Example I was having the XML of the choice field where choices were coming with special characters which was causing the issue. To overcome it, I added the choice tag of XML in the *** part and it worked.

CDATA takes the value as simple text.

```
str.Append("<CHOICE><![CDATA[" + choices[k] + "]]></CHOICE>");
```

Choices[k] are my choice value which I am fetching from code.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a choice column using the browser and enter `>=250` `<=510` etc as choices, and then look at the `SchemaXml` property of the column (for example using a tool like SharePoint Manager), you can see how they are encoded internally by SharePoint, and help troubleshooting. In this case:

```
<CHOICE>&gt;=255</CHOICE>
<CHOICE>&lt;=255</CHOICE>
<CHOICE>&gt;=510</CHOICE>
```

Perhaps you were missing the semicolon (`;`) from `lt;` and `gt;`.

CDATA is also a valid option, but for simple cases like these when only a character needs to be encoded, encoding them individually makes the code cleaner.

Comment: I tried that with semicolon but that was not valid as my choice field was generated dynamically. replacing them with &gt and &lt; was not valid as it was converting the whole xml tag in the format.